# Setting value for all fields in certain row of array

Tags: php, arrays

There probably is a function for this but I'm having a hard time finding it.

What I need is a following. If I have a matrix Mat MxN in PHP I would like to set value for all columns in a stated row. Analogy would be the following code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i<$N; $i++){
    Mat[$M][$i] = $someValue;   
}
```

I have a dynamically created keys for columns so it will be a bit complicated to do this using loops.

edited:

```
**col1 col2 col3**
   1     2    3
   4     5    6
   1     2    3
   4     5    6
   1     2    3
   4     5    6
```

after modification I would like to get (if I want to effect 4th row with a value 0)

```
**col1 col2 col3**
   1     2    3
   4     5    6
   1     2    3
   0     0    0
   1     2    3
   4     5    6
```

Comment: Can you include a sample matrix in the question and state what exactly you're trying to achieve along with the expected output?

Comment: Is `N` a typo or should it be `$N`?

Comment: @justRadojko: Still, that's some basic representation of your code. Where's the array?

Comment: @Michel it sould be $N

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
$row = 4;
$val = 0;
foreach (array_keys($Mat[$row]) as $k) {
    $Mat[$row][$k] = $val;
}
```